# How to tune UNION ALL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, select, group-by

The following MySQL query results sum of credit and debit for each account code (`acctcode`) and produces over all total using `union all`. The table `ledg_post` has 5.7 million records and is indexed. Still the query takes 1 minute to execute. Please help me to tune this query.

```
select b.acnt_code as acctcode 
,      b.disp_name as acctname
,      sum(amt_dr) as debit
,      sum(amt_cr) as credit
,      (sum(amt_dr)- sum(amt_cr)) as closingbalance
,      a.txn_code as txn_code
from   ledg_post a
,      gl_acnts b
,      mst_loan lmt
where  a.acnt_code = b.acnt_code 
group 
by     b.acnt_code
union all
select  ' ' acctcode
,       ' Grand Total ' acctname
,       sum(amt_dr) debit
,       sum(amt_cr) credit
,       (sum(amt_dr)- sum(amt_cr)) closingbalance
,       '' txn_code
from    ledg_post a
,       mst_loan  lmt
where   lmt.loan_id = a.ref_id
```

### Table Definitions

```
 create table ledg_post 
 ( txn_code  int(11) 
 , ref_id    int(11)
 , acnt_code int(11) 
 , amt_dr    decimal(20, 2) 
 , amt_cr    decimal(20, 2) 
 );

 create table gl_acnts 
 ( glm_acnt_code      int
 , glm_acnt_disp_name varchar(50) 
 );

 create table mst_loan 
 ( lmt_loan_id int(11) 
 , lmt_clnt_id int(11) 
 );
```

Comment: There is nothing to tune on the `UNION ALL` portion of the query. Your performance bottleneck is not the Union all operation, it is the aggregation operation. Also does your query run correctly? I mean, non-aggregated columns (e.g. `b.disp_name`) are not in `group by` clause...

Comment: Thanks Brown! Yeah it produce expected output.But How would i change it to improve the performance?

Comment: Just a thought... Do you have index on `b.acnt_code`?

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to use `UNION ALL`, You can achieve this using [**GROUP BY ... WITH ROLLUP**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-modifiers.html)

Try this:

```
SELECT b.acnt_code AS acctcode, IFNULL(b.disp_name, ' Grand Total ') AS acctname, 
       SUM(a.amt_dr) AS debit, SUM(a.amt_cr) AS credit, 
      (SUM(a.amt_dr)- SUM(a.amt_cr)) AS closingbalance, 
       IFNULL(a.txn_code, '') AS txn_code
FROM ledg_post a 
INNER JOIN gl_acnts b ON a.acnt_code=b.acnt_code 
GROUP BY acctcode WITH ROLLUP
```